# How can I filter records based on the maximum value of a group in Tableau Desktop?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

**How can I filter records based on the maximum value of a group in Tableau Desktop?**

I am having issue with Tableau Desktop filtering syntax.  I have a database with over 100K records, all of which have **ID**'s and **update numbers**, and I want to get the **current status** from the most recent update based on an **ID. **

A short extract of the database looks like this:

**ID                   Update Number                Current Status**
A11                  1                            Closed
B22                  1                            Open
B22                  2                            Open and Expanding
B22                  3                            Pending Closure
C33                  1                            Open and Expanding
C33                  2                            Pending Closure

I want to use Tableau Desktop to show data on only the **ID's** with the maximum **update number**.  E.G given below:

**ID                   Update Number                Current Status**
A11                  1                            Closed
B22                  3                            Pending Closure
C33                  2                            Pending Closure

And thus data would show the following:

**Current Status       Count**
Pending Closure      2
Closed               1
Open and Expanding   0
Open                 0

I am having trouble producing a filter or calculated field to only show data like this.  I created a measure with the following syntax {fixed(ID):max(update number)} but instead of providing the ID's it only returns the update numbers.

Any help would be appreciated.